# How do i sort the "DeptNumberCount" from largest to lowest?

Tags: sql, database

```
SELECT DeptName , COUNT(*) AS "DeptNumberCount"
FROM Department
GROUP BY DeptName
```

This is the code i'm running that im working on for SQL but i'm trying to get the count to show up first then the deptname, but it doesn't allow me to and i need to have it so it's largest to smallest.

Can someone please help

I've tried putting:

```
GROUP BY "DeptNumberCount" , DeptName or 
GROUP BY DeptNumberCount , DeptName
```

And the `HAVING` clause is giving me a syntax

Comment: You should use `ORDER BY DeptNumberCount DESC` clause to sort.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result

Comment: "HAVING clause is giving me a syntax" - I assume that is supposed to be "syntax error". What `HAVING` clause? What syntax error? And what does this have to do with ordering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ordering descending by the department count:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "DeptNumberCount", DeptName
FROM Department
GROUP BY DeptName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: This Worked but i wanted DeptNumberCount to show first then DeptName, How do i do that

Comment: Switch the order of the select?

Comment: Thank you, sorry i'm just overthinking. Real quick i don't need a certain data to show in the result, what would i write to remove that row